# 'Unauthorized' error when requesting 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams' from Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, unauthorized

I am trying to access **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams** in postman with Authorization and I'm getting the response as

{   "error": {
"code": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"innerError": {
"date": "2020-08-01T09:39:59",
"request-id": "d906f428-ffcd-4821-9153-f9b1976e74c1"
}   } }

As mentioned in the documentation, I have set the scopes `Team.ReadBasic.All TeamSettings.Read.All TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All User.Read.All User.ReadWrite.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All ChannelMessage.Send`

[In the Enterprise applications, I'm having Microsoft teams installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W8Ic.png)

[I have added the API permissions for type Delegated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWnfo.png)

But I can access the profile and groups. whenever I try to access teams API, I'm always getting **Unauthorized** message. Can anyone tell me, What am I missing?

Comment: Check your token [here](https://jwt.io/) if it has all the permissions listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you haven't granted admin consent for your tenant. You should use an Azure AD admin account to do this. The the **Status** will become "Granted for {your tenant}".

[image]

You should refer to [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) to get the access token by using auth code flow.

[image]